# Uniquely determining the three points which satisfy the constraints

Tags: geometry

Given two fixed lines and three points $P,Q,R$ on one line . Goal is to uniquely find three points on the other line such that they are at equal distances. ($ST=TU$) and that the line joining those points to the intial points intersect at one point (i.e. $PS,QT,RU$).Progress: idea needed  [[image]]

Comment: Take $O$ on the second line: in that case $UT=TS=0$.

Comment: What is the diference between and this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391791/method-to-find-the-common-meeting-point-of-three-lines-lying-on-a-unique-line-wi

Comment: Try a parallel through Q.

Comment: @Moti You have suggested OP to draw a line parallel to some other line through the point $Q$. What is this line?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca What you have suggested in your comment is the trivial solution. Isn't it?

Comment: @YNK Yes, of course it is.

Comment: @YNK there is only on other line in the drawing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: ThreePointsConstruction]

We give below a construction, which consists of two parts, to determine the locations of the three points $S$, $T$, and $U$ on the given line $GH$. In the first part, we construct the point $M$ on the given line $EF$ such that,
$$\dfrac{MP}{PQ} = \dfrac{MR}{RQ}.$$

What we have obtained here is four collinear points $M$,  $P$, $Q$, and $R$ in a harmonic range. In the second part, we use the constructed point $M$ to locate the three points $S$, $T$, and $U$ on $GH$.

$\underline{\text{Part 1}}$

We take an arbitrary point $A$ as shown in the in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$. After joining $A$ to $Q$, a point $B$ is marked on $AQ$. Then, we draw the lines $AP$, $AR$, $RB$, and $PB$. The two pairs of lines {$AP$, $RB$} and {$AR$, $PB$} intersect with each other at $D$ and $C$ respectively. Finally, we join $C$ to $D$ and extend it to meet $EF$ at $M$.

$\underline{\text{Part 2}}$

After constructing a line parallel to $GH$ through the point $M$, we select an arbitrary point $O$ on it. To complete the construction, we draw the three lines $PO$, $QO$, and $RO$ and extend them to cut $GH$ at $S$, $T$, and $U$. The three points satisfy the constrain,
$$ST = TU.$$

$\underline{Note\space 1}:\space$ As you have already noticed, the point $O$ can be chosen anywhere on the line that goes through $M$. For each $O$, a unique point triplet {$S$, $T$, $U$} obeying the constrain $ST = TU = k$ can be obtained. However, the value of $k$ differs from triplet to triplet.

$\underline{Note\space 2}:\space$ As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$, you may sometimes find that $M$ lies beyond the point $N$, which is the point of intersection between the given lines $EF$ and $GH$. In such instances, the point $O$ does not lie in the interior of $EF$ and $GH$. Nevertheless, the three points $S$, $T$, and $U$ satisfy the constrain $ST = TU.$

$\underline{Note\space 3}:\space$ The way OP used the word $\pmb{uniquely}$ in the problem statement gives the wrong impression that there exists only one $O$ and one set of point triplet {$S$, $T$, $U$} that satisfy the given constrain. On the contrary, there are infinite number of such sets of points.

Comment: I do not think this works - just try it with Geogbra.

Comment: @Moti I don't have to. The diagram you see at the top of my answer was drawn using Geogebra. I assume that you have also drawn a sketch of this construction to check its validity. Thank you for taking time to do that. I appreciate it very much if you could post your test sketch as an answer so that I could check it to see whether you have erred at some point or my construction fails when used in certain scenarios. By the way, there is an update to my answer is coming.

Comment: Nice method ...  .